# Modify list view with JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model

How can I make fields invisible on my list view, all items?

It is something wrong with my code now: it changes the view but the only field it is displaying is Title and Modified.

I want to display all fields but make some fields invisible.

Here is my code:

```
function getListView(listTitle, viewTitle, OnSuccess, OnError) {

var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

var web = currentContext.get_web();
var hostContext = new SP.AppContextSite(currentContext, hostUrl);
hostweb = hostContext.get_web();

var list = hostweb.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var view = list.get_views().getByTitle(viewTitle);
currentContext.load(view);

currentContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    OnSuccess(view);
},
OnError);
}


function changeView() {

var viewID;

getListView('SPopup', 'All items',
 function (view) {

     viewID = view.get_id().toString();
     console.log("View iD: " + viewID);
     view.set_jsLink("/SiteAssets/test.js");
     // view.set_title("Testar");

     view.get_listViewXml();
     // var tt = view.get_listViewXml();
     //   console.log(tt);
     var xmlListView = "<View Name='{" + viewID + "}' DefaultView='TRUE' MobileView='TRUE' MobileDefaultView='TRUE' Type='HTML' DisplayName='All items' Url='/spopup/AllItems.aspx' Level='1' BaseViewID='1' ContentTypeID='0x' ImageUrl='/_layouts/15/images/announce.png?rev=38' ><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='LinkTitle' /><FieldRef Name='Modified' /><FieldRef Name='Body' /><FieldRef Name='Group' /><FieldRef Name='Picture' /><FieldRef Name='ButtonText' /><FieldRef Name='ConfirmBoxText' /></ViewFields><RowLimit Paged='TRUE'>30</RowLimit><JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink><XslLink Default='TRUE'>main.xsl</XslLink><Toolbar Type='Standard'/></View>";

     console.log(view.get_listViewXml());
     console.log(xmlListView);

     view.set_listViewXml(xmlListView);
     //<FieldRef Name='LinkTitle' /><FieldRef Name='Modified' /><FieldRef Name='Body' /><FieldRef Name='Group' /><FieldRef Name='Picture' /><FieldRef Name='ButtonText' /><FieldRef Name='ConfirmBoxText' />

     //   <View Name="{6F93F5DA-F0DF-4164-8918-0B2E559C30C7}" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" Type="HTML" DisplayName="All items" Url="/spopup/AllItems.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/announce.png?rev=38" ><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE" /></OrderBy></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="LinkTitle" /><FieldRef Name="Modified" /><FieldRef Name="Group" /><FieldRef Name="Picture" /><FieldRef Name="ButtonText" /><FieldRef Name="ConfirmBoxText" /></ViewFields><RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit><JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink><XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink><Toolbar Type="Standard"/></View> 

     view.update();

     currentContext.executeQueryAsync(
     function success() {

         console.log("view updated ");
     },
     function error(sender, args) {

         console.log("view error " + args.get_message());
     });

     //b92c7536-c35f-40fd-80b7-f7908a08ce68 
 },
function (sender, args) {
    console.log('View Error occured:' + args.get_message());
}
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### How to delete a field from List View using SharePoint JSOM

```
function updateListView(listTitle,viewTitle,fieldsToHide,success,error) {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var view = list.get_views().getByTitle(viewTitle);
    var fieldNames = view.get_viewFields();

    context.load(view);
    context.load(fieldNames);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < fieldNames.get_count();i++) {
                var fName = fieldNames.getItemAtIndex(i);
                var found = $.inArray(fName, fieldsToHide) > -1;
                if(found) {
                   fieldNames.remove(fName); 
                }
            }
            view.update(); 
            context.executeQueryAsync(success,error);
        }, 
        error
    );
}
```

**Usage**

```
var fieldsToHide = ['CheckoutUser']; //contains an array of field names to hide
updateListView('Documents','All Documents',fieldsToHide, printViewInfo,logError);

function printViewInfo()
{
    console.log('List view has been updated');
}
function logError(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If its a static view with viewfields that you are looking for, a CAML Query like the one below should do the job-

```
CAMLQueryString = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='CategoryID' /><Value Type='Text'>78030</Value></Eq></Where></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='FirstName' /><FieldRef Name='LastName' /></ViewFields><QueryOptions /></View>";
```